# Phonegap Facebook Connect Plugin error

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to implement the facebook connect plugin for my phonegap 3.2 app. I have used [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/cordova3.0FBiOS3.8FBAndroid3.5) branch of the plugin as it better supports phonegap 3.0.

I can't debug in Ripple because I can't call the plugins from Ripple and on an android device I get the following errors when FB.init is called

[image]

[image]

here is the init call

```
FB.init({ appId: "68962476XXXXXXXX", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
```

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting these or how to even go about investigating the cause?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, rookie mistake that I should not be making.

I was initially using IntelliJ and going by the messages in logcat. I tried everything I could, and then I switched IDE to Eclipse and voila, logcat now says call to exec() of unknown plugin. I have no idea why IntelliJ did not output this or why I totally skipped Step #2 of the Manual Installation Guide!

Anyway as embarrassed as I am to say it, this sorted me out.